How does た work in this example sentence?
I came across this example sentence for 給う which I believe is the translation of a famous quote by Jefferson:
我々に生命を与えた神は我々に同時に自由を与え給うた。
How does た work here? I get that this is meant to be old fashioned and/or classical Japanese, but I thought た would attach to the 連用形 of 給う (as in 読みた in older Japanese) or to a modified version of it (as in 読んだ in modern Japanese). What is going on here? Is 給う also the 連用形? Is it a completely different construction?

給うた in Modern Japanese is [tamoːta], modern hiragana spelling たもうた, pre-1946 hiragana spelling たまうた.
[tamoːta] is example of form with U-onbin (ウ音便) followed by monophthongization of diphthong, while [tamatta] (which can be /tamaQta/ in abstract phonemic notation) is example of form with Q-onbin. (Read here about /Q/.)
U-onbin and Q-onbin are some of 6 types of onbin (in classification by Bjarke Frellesvig (2010)). Other types are: I-onbin, Ĩ-onbin, Ũ-onbin, N-onbin.
When forms with U-onbin originally appeared, they were pronounced with consecutive vowels (some vowel + [u]) or with diphthongs ending with [u̯]. In Modern Japanese, they are pronounced with single long vowel as described below.
Bjarke Frellesvig (2010, "A History of the Japanese Language", pages 191, 192, 199):

The phonological changes that triggered the introduction of long syllables were the so-called 'onbin' sound changes, which occurred some time between the late eighth and the early tenth century. The term onbin (音便) 'euphony' is used in Japanese philology to refer to a variety of phenomena, including both sound changes and morphophonological processes, which have in common that they are conceived of as being motivated by ease of articulation and involve the change of a CV syllable to a bound moraic segment. (Earlier, onbin was used in a wider sense to include also rendaku (2.6.2) or renjō (7.2.1, 11.4.21.)
(...)
A relative dating based on phonological criteria shows first that the onbin changes predate the merger of intervocalic /-p-/ with /-w-/ which took place in the second half of the tenth century (7.3.1.1): (a) /-pV/, but not /-wV/ syllables gave onbin; (b) onbin took place before /-p/, but not before /-w/. Furthermore, OJ /Ci/ syllables took part in the onbin changes, whereas OJ /Cwi/ syllables did not.
(...)
An interesting aspect of the onbin changes is that some source syllables gave both vocalic and consonantal outcomes. The basis for this is that the reduced realization in (11d) in some cases lent itself to interpretation as both a vowel and a consonant. It is not possible based on the written sources to determine any systematic distribution of the consonantal and vocalic outcomes. The consonantal outcome is often assumed to have been characteristic of eastern dialects. This is quite possible, and fits in well with an overall characterization of western Japanese as more vocalic and eastern Japanese as more consonantal, as reflected today for example in western NJ having less vowel devoicing than eastern NJ; however, for onbin this characterization is to some extent based on the present-day distribution of verbal onbin forms, which up until the end of the LMJ period was not as clear-cut as it is today (see 12.3.2).

For /pi/ syllable, possible onbin types are U-onbin and Q-onbin.
In modern Japanese, for verbs whose stem ends with /w/ (from Old Japanese /p/), -te form and derived forms (past tense -ta, -tari, -tara etc.), U-onbin is used in Kansai dialects, while Q-onbin is prevalent in standard (Tōkyō) dialect.
Diachronic rules of creating U-onbin forms of these verbs:

Transformation of /pi/ syllable (which would be [i] in modern Japanese without onbin) into /u/.
(/p/ in that /pi/ syllable was last phone of stem of verb, and /i/ was suffix of Continuative (連用形).)

Monophthongization of /Vu/ diphthongs (V = any vowel) into long monophthongs, using rules for historical process which started in Late Middle Japanese. This process was not limited to situations originating from earlier U-onbin.



[au] → [wɔː] (after consonant: [au] → [ɔː])

[wou] → [woː] (after consonant: [ou] → [oː])

[jeu] → [joː] (after consonant: [ʲeu] → [ʲoː])

[uu] → [uː]

[iu] → [juː]



Merger of [ɔː] with [oː], which occurred somewhen during Edo period.
[ɔː] → [oː]
In pre-1946 kana orthography, original /ɔː/ was spelt with "au"/"afu"-type syllables (あう, あふ, わう, わふ, かう, かふ, さう, さふ etc.), /oː/ coming from /ou/ was spelt with "ou"/"ofu"-type syllables (おう, おふ, をう, をふ, こう, こふ, そう, そふ etc.), and /oː/ coming from /eu/ was spelt with "eu"/"efu"-type syllables (えう, えふ, ゑう, ゑふ, けう, けふ, せう, せふ etc.).
In Portuguese sources about Japanese from 16th / 17th century, syllable [wɔː] was usually spelt with "vǒ" or "uǒ", other [ɔː] was usually spelt with "ǒ", syllable [woː] was usually spelt with "vô" or "uô", and other [oː] was usually spelt with "ô". (E.g. Vocabulario da Lingoa de Iapam, Arte da Lingoa de Iapam)



Examples of development for some verbs:

[ap-] → [aw-] (會ふ → 会う):
U-onbin:
[apitʲe] → [autʲe] → [wɔːtʲe] → [woːtʲe] → [oːte]
[apitaru] → [autaru] → [wɔːtaru] → [wɔːta]→ [woːta] → [oːta]
Q-onbin:
[apitʲe] → [attʲe] → [atte]
[apitaru] → [attaru] → [atta]

[kap-] → [kaw-] (買ふ → 買う):
U-onbin:
[kapitʲe] → [kautʲe] → [kɔːtʲe] → [koːtʲe] → [koːte]
[kapitaru] → [kautaru] → [kɔːtaru] → [kɔːta]→ [koːta]
Q-onbin:
[kapitʲe] → [kattʲe] → [katte]
[kapitaru] → [kattaru] → [katta]

[tamap-]→ [tamaw-] (給ふ → 給う):
U-onbin:
[tamapitʲe] → [tamautʲe] → [tamɔːtʲe] → [tamoːtʲe] → [tamoːte]
[tamapitaru] → [tamautaru] → [tamɔːtaru] → [tamɔːta] → [tamoːta]
Q-onbin:
[tamapitʲe] → [tamattʲe] → [tamatte]
[tamapitaru] → [tamattaru] → [tamatta]

[wep-] → [jew-] (醉ふ → 酔う) is historical example for /eu/, but this verb had further irregular levelling of stem to [jow-]:
U-onbin:
[wepitʲe] → [weutʲe] → [joːtʲe] → [joːte]
[wepitaru] → [weutaru] → [joːtaru] → [joːta]
Q-onbin:
[wepitʲe] → [wettʲe] → [jettʲe] → *[ette] (replaced with [jotte])
[wepitaru] → [wettaru] → [jettaru] → [jetta] → *[etta] (replaced with [jotta])

[sasop-] → [sasow-] (誘ふ → 誘う):
U-onbin:
[sasopitʲe] → [sasoutʲe] → [sasoːtʲe] → [sasoːte]
[sasopitaru] → [sasoutaru] → [sasoːtaru] → [sasoːta]
Q-onbin:
[sasopitʲe] → [sasottʲe] → [sasotte]
[sasopitaru] → [sasottaru] → [sasotta]

[arasop-] → [arasow-] (爭ふ → 争う):
U-onbin:
[arasopitʲe] → [arasoutʲe] → [arasoːtʲe] → [arasoːte]
[arasopitaru] → [arasoutaru] → [arasoːtaru] → [arasoːta]
Q-onbin:
[arasopitʲe] → [arasottʲe] → [arasotte]
[arasopitaru] → [arasottaru] → [arasotta]

[kup-] → [kuw-] (食う):
U-onbin:
[kupitʲe] → [kuutʲe] → [kuːtʲe] → [kuːte]
[kupitaru] → [kuutaru] → [kuːtaru] → [kuːta]
Q-onbin:
[kupitʲe] → [kuttʲe] → [kutte]
[kupitaru] → [kuttaru] → [kutta]

[ip-] → [iw-] (言ふ → 言う):
U-onbin:
[ipitʲe] → [iutʲe] → [juːtʲe] → [juːte]
[ipitaru] → [iutaru] → [juːtaru] → [juːta]
Q-onbin:
[ipitʲe] → [ittʲe] → [itte]
[ipitaru] → [ittaru] → [itta]



In standard (Tōkyō) Japanese, several verbs have conjugation pattern with U-onbin for these forms (either as preservation of archaic feature, or borrowed from Kansai dialects):

[kop-] → [kow-] (請ふ・ 乞ふ → 請う・ 乞う):
[kopitʲe] → [koutʲe] → [koːtʲe] → [koːte]
[kopitaru] → [koutaru] → [koːtaru] → [koːta]

[kop-] → [kow-] (戀ふ → 恋う):
[kopitʲe] → [koutʲe] → [koːtʲe] → [koːte]
[kopitaru] → [koutaru] → [koːtaru] → [koːta]

[top-] → [tow-] (問ふ → 問う):
[topitʲe] → [toutʲe] → [toːtʲe] → [toːte]
[topitaru] → [toutaru] → [toːtaru] → [toːta]



Historically monophthongization of diphthongs was occurring also in Positive Conclusive (終止形) / Attributive (連体形). Example:

[ap-] → [aw-] (會ふ → 会う):
Continuative (連用形) [awi] → [ai]
Positive Conclusive (終止形) / Attributive (連体形) [au] → [wɔː] → [woː]
Negative Conclusive (終止形) / Attributive (連体形) [awanu]


In Modern Japanese, divergence between surface forms of stem of such verbs was levelled, in most cases by reverting of change in Positive Conclusive (終止形) / Attributive (連体形) and restoring of vowel still seen in some other forms (e.g. Continuative (連用形) or Negative) (e.g. [woː] was replaced with [au]).
Example of exception:

[saᵐburapu] (侍ふ・候ふ) → (Ũ-onbin) [saũrapu] → [saũrau] → [saurau] → [sɔːrɔː] → [soːroː] → [soːrou] (候う)


[juː] pronunciation of 言う is some preservation of monophthongization of /iu/ diphthong.

Examples of onbin in nouns:

U-onbin:
(弟) [otopito] → [otouto] → [otoːto]
(妹) [imopito] → [imouto] → [imoːto]
(新田) [nipita] → [niuta] → [nʲuːta]

Ũ-onbin:
(小路) [komiti] → [koũⁿdi] → [kouⁿdi] → [koːⁿd͡ʑi] → [koːd͡ʑi]
(狩人) [kariᵐbito] → [kariũⁿdo] → [kariuⁿdo] → [karʲuːⁿdo] → [karʲuːdo]
(商人) [akiᵐbito] → [akiũⁿdo] → [akiuⁿdo] → [akʲuːⁿdo] → [akʲuːdo]

N-onbin:
(商人) [akiᵐbito] → [akinⁿdo] → [akindo]
(東) [pimukasi] → [piŋᵑɡasi] → [ɸiŋᵑɡaɕi] → [çiŋɡaɕi] (at some time, developed variant without /N/, leading ultimately to modern [çiɡaɕi])

Q-onbin:
(新田) [nipita] → [nitta]



Does that imply this specific translation uses Kansaiben?

@Saegusa Verb 給う itself is somehow archaic. That sentence could be either in Kansai-ben, or it could be generally intended as archaic-sounding and not necessarily specific to Kansai-ben. I suspect that U-onbin forms also existed as variant forms of verbs in eastern dialects, but have fallen out of use. U-onbin is well alive in some nouns, e.g. おとうと, いもうと, しろうと, かりゅうど.
